# Tight upper tail bound for $\Pr\left(X>\mu(1+\delta)\right)$ where $X=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\alpha^nU_n$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

> Fix $X_0 = 1$, $0 < \alpha < 1$, and $(U_n)$ i.i.d. uniform on $(0, 1)$, and define
>   $$X_{n+1} = \alpha X_n + \alpha U_n\qquad X = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n$$
>   I'm looking for a reasonably tight upper tail bound on $X$, i.e. $\Pr\left(X>\mu(1+\delta)\right)$.

A few things I've tried so far:

**1)** Constructing the MGF, for taking a Chernoff bound. The MGF produces a recurrence relation, I tried to solve this a few ways

1a) substitute an exponential; this doesn't work because the $\alpha$ scaling changes the "frequency" of the exponential

1b) substitute a polynomial or a Taylor series; I can compute a first few terms but don't recognize a pattern and the terms don't appear to converge quickly for a bound

1c) expand the recurrence and look for a "telescoping" trick, no dice

1d) try a symbolic solver like wolfram alpha; it times out,

**2)** assume the tail of the PDF is bounded above by an exponential; but the exponential is not invariant under the scaling (as above) so it doesn't look tight

**3)** assume the tail of the PDF (within range of the last $U_n$ is bounded above by an arbitrary function, extract a simpler recurrence relation and try to solve that

**4)** try substituting standard lists of distributions

**5)** skim literature for fixed-point distributions like Pareto, but these are for iid sums

**6)** try to adapt the neat observation that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \text{Bernoulli} / 2^i \sim \text{U}(0, 1)$, but that's specific to $\text{Bernoulli}$ and $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Nice to know. And your tries to solve this are?

Comment: A few things I've tried so far: (1) Constructing the MGF, for taking a Chernoff bound. The MGF produces a recurrence relation, I tried to solve this a few ways (1a) substitute an exponential; this doesn't work because the $\alpha$ scaling changes the "frequency" of the exponential (1b) substitute a polynomial or a Taylor series; I can compute a first few terms but don't recognize a pattern and the terms don't appear to converge quickly for a bound (1c) expand the recurrence and look for a "telescoping" trick, no dice (1d) try a symbolic solver like wolfram alpha; it times out,

Comment: (2) assume the tail of the PDF is bounded above by an exponential; but the exponential is not invariant under the scaling (as above) so it doesn't look tight (3) assume the tail of the PDF (within range of the last $U_n$ is bounded above by an arbitrary function, extract a simpler recurrence relation and try to solve that (4) try substituting standard lists of distributions

Comment: (5) skim literature for fixed-point distributions like Pareto, but these are for iid sums (6) try to adapt the neat observation that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \text{Bernoulli} / 2^i \sim \text{U}(0, 1)$, but that's specific to $\text{Bernoulli}$ and $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: That's it so far; I'll append more if I find anything interesting.

Comment: Right, but all of these should have been in your question from the start. Anyway, I guess that $\mu=E(X)$, that is, $$\mu=\frac{\alpha}{2(1-\alpha)}$$ Then computing the second moment of $Y$ distributed as $X$ which is $$Y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha^nU_n$$ yields $$\mathrm{var}(X)=\frac{\alpha^2}{12(1-\alpha^2)}$$ hence the simplest application of Bienaymé-Chebychev yields $$\Pr(X\geqslant\mu(1+\delta))\leqslant\frac{1-\alpha}{3(1+\alpha)\delta^2}$$

Comment: Certainly we have $\operatorname{Pr}(X > \mu(1+\delta)) = 0$ if $\delta \geq 1$. Which range of $\delta$ are you interested in?

Comment: Anyway we have the following computation: $$ \operatorname{Pr}(X_n \leq \epsilon) = \frac{\epsilon^n}{n!} \alpha^{1 - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}}, \qquad 0 < \epsilon < \alpha^n. $$ This might be used in a heuristic argument to obtain an asymptotic decay of the 'left-tail' $\operatorname{Pr}(X \leq \epsilon)$.

Comment: Did, thanks for improving the presentation of my question. I confirm your bound. However it does not seem particularly tight; I'll put together a counterexample.

Comment: Consider $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$, $\delta=1$, i.e. $\text{Pr}(X \geq 1)$. The given Bienaymé-Chebychev bound produces $\frac{1}{3}$, whereas since $U_n<1$ with probability 1 we obtain $\text{Pr}(X \geq 1) = 0$. I'm torturing the bound here sorry, but I'm particularly interested in the upper tail like $\text{Pr}(X\geq \mu(1 + \delta)) < 0.01$, say.

Comment: Sangchul, good point. I am interested to minimize $\delta$ subject to $\text{Pr}(X \geq \mu(1 + \delta)) < 0.01$ say. The motivation is a resource allocation problem with stochastic consumption; I'd like to ensure sufficient resources with high probability.

Comment: Sangchul, I am interested in the right-tail. The left-tail analysis that you give is interesting, I will see if I can apply something like this to the right-tail.

Comment: Oops, I incorrectly said that the Bienaymé-Chebychev bound produces $\frac{1}{3}$, whereas it appears to be $\frac{1}{9}$. However I still aspire to a tighter bound.

Comment: Sangchul, oops I now see the distribution is symmetric under a change of variables $Y_n = 2\mu - X_n$, which should be expected as the sum of symmetric random variables. So left-tail bounds are right-tail bounds.

Comment: You can send notification to people by adding @ in front of their names, for instance, @SangchulLee. And you are right, $X$ has the same law as $2\mu - X$, so both sides can be used equally. I will try to check if the tail for $X_n$ can be utilized to our problem.